# implement with the function getopt a program to add 2 vectors

Tags: c

How can I implement with the function getopt a program to add 2 vectors?

like this:

This part is when the program is already executed.

$ ./practica -a 1,2,3 -b 4,5,6

5,7,9

I have this code,but this is not working well :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int At = 0, Bt = 0, x, i;
    int A_X, B_X;
    char s2[4] = " ,";
    char s3[4] = " \0";
    char *ptrA, *ptrB;
    char A[200], B[200];
    char *aname = "VALORES_A", *bname = "VALORES_B", *cname;
    char usage[] = "usage: %s -a \,0 VALORES\, -b \,0 VALORES\,\n";
    int opc;
    while ((opc = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opc)
        {
            case 'a':
                //  printf("Los valores de A son:%s",optarg);
                aname = optarg;
                break;
            case 'b':
                //  printf("Los valores de B  son:%s",optarg);
                bname = optarg;
                break;
        }
    }


    printf("Valores de A:%s\n", aname);
    printf("Valores de B:%s\n", bname);

    i = 0;
    ptrA = strtok(aname, (s2));
    A_X = atoi(ptrA);
    while ((ptrA = strtok(NULL, s2)) != NULL)
    {
        x = atoi(ptrA);
        A[i] = x;
        i++;
        At++;
    }

    printf("\n A total= %d", At);


    i = 0;
    ptrB = strtok(bname, s2);
    B_X = atoi(ptrB);
    while ((ptrB = strtok(NULL, s2)) != NULL)
    {
        x = atoi(ptrB);
        B[i] = x;
        i++;
        Bt++;
    }
    printf("\n B total= %d", Bt);
    /*
    ///Verificacion
    if(A_X!=0){
        printf("\n Los valores deben iniciar con 0 al inicio -a \"0 Valor   
    Valor\"\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(B_X!=0){
        printf("\n Los valores deben iniciar con 0 al inicio -b \"0 Valor 
    Valor\"\n");
        exit(1);
    }*/
    ///Verificar Negativos
    for (i = 0; i < At; i++)
    {
        x = A[i];
        if ((x == 0) || (x < 0))
        {
            printf("\nNo se permiten letras, numeros negativos y/o ceros");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Bt; i++)
    {
        x = B[i];
        if ((x == 0) || (x < 0))
        {
            printf("\nNo se permiten letras, numeros negativos y/o ceros");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    ///valores de A
    printf("\nA= ");
    for (i = 0; i < At; i++)
        fprintf(stdout, "%d, ", A[i]);

    printf("\nB= ");
    for (i = 0; i < Bt; i++)
        printf("%d, ", B[i]);
    /*
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                        cname[i]=aname[i]+bname[i];
          }
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                        printf("%s,",cname[j]);
          }
     */
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "not working well"? What happens when you run the program? What is the actual and expected output? Have you tried debugging the program (either run in a debugger and step through the code line by line, or by printing lots of extra info in the program)?

Comment: And does it even *compile* well? There are some things I can see that should give you warnings. Also, you have two different pointers that can both be pointing to the same memory (`aname` and `bname`), which is probably the source of your problem.

Comment: `A[0]` instead of `A_X`, B ditto.

Comment: "Los valores deben iniciar con 0 al inicio" but `$ ./practica -a 1,2,3 -b 4,5,6

5,7,9`

Comment: if you pass `$ ./practicia -a ,1,2,3 -b ,4,5,6`. It works perfectly fine. Please check your `while loop`. `x` variable under the while loop never gets `1` & `4` if you pass `-a 1,2,3`, But if you pass `-a ,1,2,3` it does the charm.